# Forward and reverse query to ManyToMany relation Django

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Task(MPTTModel, TimeStampedModel, StartFinishModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_after_end = models.ManyToManyField('self',                                    
                                             related_name='s2e_relation',
                                             blank=True) 
    #s2e means that task can't start before related tasks end
```

How can I get all tasks, which can't start before this task ends and all tasks, which have to end before this task can start.

```
Let's say 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

I have id `2`. I want to find `3` and with another query `1`.
To find 3 I can use `Task.objects.get(id = 2).start_after_end.all()`
How can I find `1`?

**UPDATE 1**
Actually find out bigger problem - if I select `2 related to 1` - 1 immidiately changes relation to `1 is related to 2`

Comment: You need to make the relation assymetrical.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  what do u mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make a relation with `'self'`, by default Django will make the relation *symmetrical*. This means that if an object `a` has as friend `b`, then `b` automatically has as friend `a`. So this means that the relation here will look like:

```
# symmetrical relation
1  <---> 2 <---> 3
```

It thus means that for:

```
task1.start_after_end.all()  # ==> [2]
task2.start_after_end.all()  # ==> [1, 3]
task3.start_after_end.all()  # ==> [2]
```

So that here both `1` and `3` will be seen as `Task2.start_after_end.all()`s. You probably do *not* want that: you want the relation to be *non-symetrical*.

So you should edit the field to:

```
class Task(MPTTModel, TimeStampedModel, StartFinishModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_after_end = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',                                    
        related_name='s2e_relation',
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True
    )
```

Now the above will look like:

```
# asymmetrical relation
1   ---> 2  ---> 3
```

Note that *non-symmetrical* relations are *not* *anti-symmetrical* relations. It is still possible to add `task1` to the `start_after_end` of `task2`, but it will not do this automatically in case you add `task2` to the `start_after_end` of `task1`.

So now if that is done, it means that for `some_task`, we get the next tasks with:

```
my_task.start_after_end.all()  # the next ones
```

and we get the ones before with the `related_name`:

```
my_task.s2e_relation.all()     # the previous ones
```

So for example:

```
task1 = Task.objects.create(name='task1')
task2 = Task.objects.create(name='task2')
task3 = Task.objects.create(name='task3')

task1.start_after_end.add(task2)
task2.start_after_end.add(task3)
```

Then if we trigger the relations, we get:

```
task1.start_after_end.all()  # ==> [2]
task2.start_after_end.all()  # ==> [3]
task3.start_after_end.all()  # ==> []

task1.s2e_relation.all()  # ==> []
task2.s2e_relation.all()  # ==> [1]
task3.s2e_relation.all()  # ==> [2]
```

Comment: wow, as always great answer! thanks for help, I will test it now, but I feel that should work :)

Comment: @Chiefir: note that if you already added data, this might result in some problems, so you might have to fix the *existing* data.

Comment: yep, I guess `flush` and `loaddata` will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to use `related_name='s2e_relation'` passed in `ManyToManyField`

You can do so by:

```
Task.objects.get(id=2).s2e_relation.all()
```

Comment: yes the relation should be `asymmetrical` and then this should work.